# Format a removable media device without password

Tags: format

I want to format a usb flash drive, and it really is a pain to enter the administrative account just for that, and moreover does that mean that a user who own a usb drive can't format it if he doesn't know the root password?

I understand that formatting a drive is a *risky* task, and obviously has to be protected when the drive being formatted is 'system' partition (for example is you have the /home at a different disk partition), but I don't see why formatting an external usb should be protected.

So, is there an easy way to format removable media (usb flash, sd cards, etc...) without needing root access and without creating a security hole by grating format privileges to anyone (or more properly to any device) ?

BTW, I'm using the Kde desktop so if the solution is Kde better. Terminal solutions are also acceptable but I would really like it to be more user friendly (GUI).